# Should LIKE 'searchstr%' use an index?

Tags: sql, sqlite, cocoa, query-optimization, sql-like

I have a database with several fields :

```
word_id — INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY
word — TEXT
...
```

And ~150k rows. Since this is a dictionary, I'm searching for a word with mask `'search_string%'` using `LIKE`. It used to work, taking 15ms to find matching rows. The table has an index for a field `'word'`.

I modified the table (some fields which are out of the scope) and it's taking 400ms to execute a query, so I understand that as it fails to use index now. Straightforward query with `=` instead of `LIKE` shows 10ms result. What's happening here?

Comment: i think so, you probably want to look at b-tree as b-tree are efficient in range query and like comparison.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't index suppose the creation of b-tree? You mean, I should create a b-tree by myself?

Comment: Is the % always only at the end of your search term, never the start ?

Comment: Yeah, always in the beginning.

Comment: Maybe try dropping and recreating the index?

Comment: there are a few index type that can be specified during creating an index. example, in mysql it has, b-tree, hash and r-tree. but since you are using sqlite, am not familiar with it and so sqlite expert can comment further.

Comment: Thank you. I've already tried recreating an index, making several indexes for several fields and so on. I remember, that several months ago, when I was creating these indexes (that worked), I've been using an unusual query like `CREATE INDEX idxname ON table(words) __SOMETHING_HERE__` and I can't remember what was it on the end of the query. Maybe I had a dream about it, because it's highly unlikely ))

Comment: You should try to use `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` to see what's going on with your query.

Comment: By the way, how would I do this on iPhone? I mean, just type `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT ...` and watch what's up in console or what?

Comment: A good candidate for the clustered index would be `(word, word_id)` if that is possible in SQLite.

Comment: nah, it appears to be 10 times slower with clustered index

Answer (score 41, accepted):

An index cannot safely be used in this case. A naive implementation would transform this:

`... WHERE word LIKE 'search_string%'`

into

`... WHERE word >= 'search_string' AND word < 'search_strinh'`

by incrementing the last character of the search string. The greater-than and less-than operators can use an index, where LIKE cannot.

Unfortunately, that won't work in the general case. The `LIKE` operator is case-insensitive, which means that `'a' LIKE 'A'` is true. The above transformation would break any search string with capitalized letters.

In some cases, however, you *know* that case sensitivity is irrelevant for a particular column, and the above transformation is safe. In this case, you have two options.

1. Use the `NOCASE` collating sequence on the index that covers this particular field.
2. Change the behavior of the `LIKE` operator program-wide by running `PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = ON;`

Either of these behaviors will enable SQLite to transparently do the above transformation for you; you just keep using `LIKE` as always, and SQLite will rewrite the underlying query to use the index.

You can read more about "The LIKE Optimization" on the [SQLite Query Optimizer Overview page](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#the_like_optimization).

Comment: The syntax of using `COLLATE NOCASE` with index is `CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name COLLATE NOCASE);` if anyone interested.

Answer (score 3):

**`GLOB prefix*` workaround**

This method does use the index, and so it is a good workaround for `LIKE prefix%` that doesn't require modifying the table collation:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn GLOB 'myprefix*'
```

See also: [Can an index on a text column speed up prefix based LIKE queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58684279/can-an-index-on-a-text-column-speed-up-prefix-based-like-queries)

Tested on Sqlite 3.40.1, Ubuntu 23.04 on a `TEXT` column of a large-ish database I have lying around with 750 M rows. Query results are almost instantaneous.