# Can an index on a text column speed up prefix based LIKE queries?

Tags: sqlite, indexing, text, sql-like

In SQLite, can an index on a text column speed up prefix based `LIKE` queries on the column?

For example, if I have a `TEXT` column named `path` and I run a query similar to `WHERE path LIKE '/path/to/some/dir/%'`, will this query be able to benefit from an index on that `path` column?

Comment: Sometimes, yes. See https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#the_like_optimization for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LIKE` will not benefit from the index ( with default option )  but you can rewrite you query by using `GLOB` or `BETWEEN` .

***SOLUTION 1***

With a regular index :

**like**   => not optimized

```
sqlite> explain query plan select * from pathdta where path like '/path/to/some/dir/a%' ;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE pathdta
```

**GLOB** => optimized

```
sqlite> explain query plan select * from pathdta where path GLOB '/path/to/some/dir/a*' ;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE pathdta USING COVERING INDEX ix_pathdta_dta (path>? AND path<?)
```

**greater** => optimized

```
sqlite> explain query plan  select * from pathdta where path >= '/path/to/some/dir/a' ;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE pathdta USING COVERING INDEX ix_pathdta_dta (path>?)
```

**equality** => optimized

```
sqlite> explain query plan  select * from pathdta where path = '/path/to/some/dir/a' ;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE pathdta USING COVERING INDEX ix_pathdta_dta (path=?)
```

**between** => optimized

```
sqlite> explain query plan  select * from pathdta
   ...>    where path between '/path/to/some/dir/a' and '/path/to/some/dir/b' ;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE pathdta USING COVERING INDEX ix_pathdta_dta (path>? AND path<?)
```

***SOLUTION 2***

use a `collate nocase` index .

**like** => optimized

```
sqlite> explain query plan select * from pathdta where path like '/path/to/some/dir/a%' ;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE pathdta USING COVERING INDEX ix_pathdta_dta (path>? AND path<?)
```

**glob** => not optimized

```
sqlite> explain query plan select * from pathdta where path GLOB '/path/to/some/dir/a*' ;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE pathdta
```

**greater** => not optimized

```
sqlite> explain query plan  select * from pathdta where path >= '/path/to/some/dir/a' ;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE pathdta
```

**equality** => not optimized

```
sqlite> explain query plan  select * from pathdta where path = '/path/to/some/dir/a' ;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE pathdta
```

**between** => not optimized

```
sqlite> explain query plan  select * from pathdta
   ...>    where path between '/path/to/some/dir/a' and '/path/to/some/dir/b' ;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE pathdta
```

Comment: Sqlite will do that rewriting for you in some cases. See my comment on the original question.

Comment: @Shawn it did not rewrite in my test , please look my sqlfiddle

Comment: Your test doesn't fulfill the needed constraints for the optimization. (Plus your manual version won't match all the same things the original `LIKE` will.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will, with the right index. If using the default case-insensitive `LIKE` mode, the index also needs to be case-insensitive. There are other restrictions too, see the [`LIKE` optimization documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#the_like_optimization) for full details (It's quite long and hard to summarize).

Example:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE paths(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, path TEXT);
sqlite> CREATE INDEX paths_idx_path ON paths(path); -- case sensitive index
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM paths WHERE path LIKE 'foo%';
QUERY PLAN
`--SCAN TABLE paths
sqlite> DROP INDEX paths_idx_path;
sqlite> CREATE INDEX paths_idx_path ON paths(path COLLATE NOCASE); -- case insensitive index
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM paths WHERE path LIKE 'foo%';
QUERY PLAN
`--SEARCH TABLE paths USING COVERING INDEX paths_idx_path (path>? AND path<?)
```

As you can see, with the case-insensitive index, the query gets rewritten to do a search of rows in a particular range, not a scan of all rows in the table.

You can also specify that all comparisons of the column be case-insensitive in the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE paths(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, path TEXT COLLATE NOCASE);
```

and then the index doesn't need the `COLLATE` because it's already implied.